# How do I make json dumped files hidden

Tags: python

When using the json module, is there a way I can set any file I dump to immediately turn into a hidden file (Instead of having to go into properties and tick the hidden box)

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Currently on Windows

Comment: Try the answer I posted

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["attrib","+H","<filename>.json"])
```

Try this